# How to protect asp.net application to run only on specified domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm going to publish an asp.net pre-compiled web site on shared hosting account but I don't want my code to be copied and able to run on another domain. I need to check domain and if not example.com or www.example.com redirect to error page or show error as response.

**EDIT: Here is my solution based on given answers**

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] safeDomains = new string[] { "localhost",
    "example.com", "www.example.com" };

    if (!((IList)safeDomains).Contains(Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]))
    {
        Response.Write("Domain not allowed!");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you worried that someone takes your source/assembly and runs it on its own site or something else? There is not much you can do if you can't protect code/assembly from beeing taken and used on some other server.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I'm just worried about easy copy & use of my assembly by other stuff who have access to served files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the domain is known ahead of time, why not check the SERVER_NAME server variable in your global.asax's Application_BeginRequest handler?  If it's not one of your predetermined domains, then kick the request to an error page.

This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/03/09/viewing-all-server-variables-for-a-site.aspx) shows you the various server variables available and some sample output.

Rick Strahl also has a very good [blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx) about parsing variables to get all sorts of information about your request.  It's a good reference.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Request.Url.Host` of the incoming request. Does it match? The determined might be able the circumvent this by placing the server on a private network and proxying requests to it, but it's probably the best you can manage.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://mancosoftware.blogspot.com/2010/10/protect-aspnet-application-using-name.html) demonstrates how the domain name protection for ASP.NET applications can be implemented using professional licensing system.

Answer (score 0):

and maybe check domain with your database on your own server to validate domain with a web service.
i mean you can have a table on your master website called 'Websites'
and in child website get domain name
then with web service check your master database if this domain exist